# OpenCL in C : can't free gpu memory

Tags: c, matrix, memory, gpu, opencl

I'm writing an algorithm that needs to be able to multiply matrices quickly. I tried using threads, then I thought about using GPU.

I first wanted to use CUDA but couldn't make it work, so I used OpenCL.

I used code I found on the Internet and changed it to make it work with my program.

However, the GPU memory keeps increasing until there's no memory left. The code seems to be freeing the memory correctly.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Here's the code I'm using to load OpenCL and multiply the matrices:

```
/***************
  Copyright (c) 2015, MedicineYeh
  All rights reserved.

  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

  Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *****************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include "matrix.h"

#define checkErr(fun, statement) err = fun;\
                                 if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {statement}
#define checkExit(value, message) if (value == 0) {printf(message); goto release;}

//define function 

double get_event_exec_time(cl_event event)
{
    cl_ulong start_time, end_time;
    /*Get start device counter for the event*/
    clGetEventProfilingInfo (event,
            CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,
            sizeof(cl_ulong),
            &start_time,
            NULL);
    /*Get end device counter for the event*/
    clGetEventProfilingInfo (event,
            CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,
            sizeof(cl_ulong),
            &end_time,
            NULL);
    /*Convert the counter values to milli seconds*/
    double total_time = (end_time - start_time) * 1e-6;
    return total_time;
}

cl_program load_program(cl_context context, cl_device_id device, const char* filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rt");
    size_t length;
    char *data;
    char *build_log;
    size_t ret_val_size;
    cl_program program = 0;
    cl_int status = 0;
    if(!fp) return 0;

    // get file length
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // read program source
    data = (char *)malloc(length + 1);
    fread(data, sizeof(char), length, fp);
    data[length] = '\0';

    // create and build program 
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&data, 0, 0);
    if (program == 0) return 0;

    status = clBuildProgram(program, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (status != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Error:  Building Program from file %s\n", filename);
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &ret_val_size);
        build_log = (char *)malloc(ret_val_size + 1);
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, ret_val_size, build_log, NULL);
        build_log[ret_val_size] = '\0';
        printf("Building Log:\n%s", build_log);
        return 0;
    }

    return program;
}

void gpu_mul(matrix m1, matrix m2, matrix r)
{
    cl_int err = 0;
    cl_uint num = 0;
    cl_platform_id *platforms = NULL;
    cl_context_properties prop[3] = {0};
    cl_context context = 0;
    cl_device_id *devices = NULL;
    cl_command_queue queue = 0;
    cl_program program = 0;
    cl_mem cl_a = 0, cl_b = 0, cl_res = 0;
    cl_kernel adder = 0;
    cl_event event;
    unsigned int num_total_devices = 0;
    char devname[16][256] = {{0}};
    size_t cb, work_size;
    unsigned int i;

    int m = m1.rows;
    int n = m1.columns;
    int p = m2.columns;
    double *a = m1.value;
    double *b = m2.value;
    double *res = r.value;

    checkErr(clGetPlatformIDs(0, 0, &num), 
             printf("Unable to get platforms\n");
             return;
             );

    platforms = (cl_platform_id *)malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id) * num);
    checkErr(clGetPlatformIDs(num, platforms, NULL), 
             printf("Unable to get platform ID\n");
             return;
             );

    checkErr(clGetPlatformIDs(0, 0, &num), 
             printf("Unable to get platforms\n");
             return;
             );

    //printf("Found %d platforms:\n", num);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        char str[1024];
        clGetPlatformInfo (platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, 1024, str, NULL);
        //printf("\t%d: %s\n", i, str);
    }

    prop[0] = CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM;
    prop[1] = (cl_context_properties)platforms[0];
    prop[2] = 0;
    context = clCreateContextFromType(prop, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    checkExit(context, "Can't create OpenCL context\n");

    clGetContextInfo(context, CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, 0, NULL, &cb);
    devices = (cl_device_id *)malloc(cb);
    clGetContextInfo(context, CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, cb, devices, 0);
    checkExit(cb, "Can't get devices\n");
    num_total_devices = cb / sizeof(cl_device_id);

    //printf("Found %d devices:\n", num_total_devices);
    for (i = 0; i < num_total_devices; i++) {
        clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_NAME, 256, devname[i], 0);
        //printf("\t%d: %s", i, devname[i]);
        clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(int), &cb, 0);
        //printf("  - %d\n", (int)cb);
    }

    //Specify the queue to be profile-able
    queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices[0], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, 0);
    checkExit(queue, "Can't create command queue\n");

    program = load_program(context, devices[0], "matrixmul_kernel.cl");
    checkExit(program, "Fail to build program\n");

    cl_a = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(double) * m * n, a, NULL);
    cl_b = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(double) * n * p, b, NULL);
    cl_res = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(double) * m * p , res, NULL);
    if (cl_a == 0 || 
        cl_b == 0 || 
        cl_res == 0) {
            if(cl_a==0)
                printf("Can't create OpenCL buffer (cl_a) \n");
            if(cl_b==0)
                printf("Can't create OpenCL buffer (cl_b) \n");
            if(cl_res==0)
                printf("Can't create OpenCL buffer (cl_res) \n");
        goto release;
    }
//    adder = clCreateKernel(program, "adder", &err);
    adder = clCreateKernel(program, "test", &err);
    if (err == CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME) printf("CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME\n");
    checkExit(adder, "Can't load kernel\n");

    clSetKernelArg(adder, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &cl_a);
    clSetKernelArg(adder, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &cl_b);
    clSetKernelArg(adder, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &cl_res);
    clSetKernelArg(adder, 3, sizeof(cl_int), &m);
    clSetKernelArg(adder, 4, sizeof(cl_int), &n);
    clSetKernelArg(adder, 5, sizeof(cl_int), &p);
    work_size = m * p;

    checkErr(clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, adder, 1, 0, &work_size, 0, 0, 0, &event),
             printf("Can't enqueue kernel\n");
            );
    checkErr(clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, cl_res, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(double) * work_size, res, 0, 0, 0),
             printf("Can't enqueue read buffer\n");
            );
    clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
    //printf("Execution Time: %.04lf ms\n\n", get_event_exec_time(event));

    //Make sure everything is done before we do anything
    clFinish(queue);

release:
    clReleaseKernel(adder);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseMemObject(cl_a);
    clReleaseMemObject(cl_b);
    clReleaseMemObject(cl_res);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseContext(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many bytes per iteration are you leaking? That will give you an idea of what you are leaking. If it is small, I noticed that you take a cl_event object in `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` (the one you call `clWaitForEvents` with), but you never free it with `clReleaseEvent` afterwards. For other items, you could check the reference count to see if something got a reference you were not aware of.

Comment: I'm loosing about 109 Mib every time I multiply two 1000*1000 matrices.
I'll try to free the clEnqueueNDRangeKernel but I'm not sure it'd be taking that much memory !